# Depth buffer only show blue color

Tags: graphics, rendering, depth-buffer

I'm trying to implement Light Prepass rendering in RenderMonkey. So far, in Normal+Depth pass, it seems like Normal buffer is getting correct result, but Depth buffer only show one color. How can I check if my Depth buffer is correct or not?
Workspace download link: http://www.mediafire.com/?jq3jmantyxw

Comment: Can we see an image of the resulting depth buffer?

Comment: It's just plain light blue. Nothing else. If you want to see, use this link http://www.flickr.com/photos/50600408@N07/4772680803/
Actually, you can just download the workspace I uploaded above and try it for your self

Answer (score 0):

The light blue is actually RGB values `0.0, 1.0, 1.0`. Since depth is (usually) a single channel representing Z, when sampled from texture it's returned in the first channel, red. Missing channels green, blue and alpha will have 1.0 substituted by the hardware.

Your download link is non-functional, since it's been 2 years I suspect.

You should ensure your pixel shader is returning both `COLOR0` and `COLOR1` semantics (note that depth is a `float4` despite the output being a single channel texture):

```
struct PS_OUT { float4 color : COLOR0; float4 depth : COLOR1; };

PS_OUT ps_main( PS_INPUT Input )
{
    PS_OUT Output;
    // your color shader here
    Output.color = myFinalColor;
    Output.depth = myFinalDepth;  // e.g. Input.posz / Input.posw from your vertex shader
    return Output;
}
```

Depending on your camera settings, you could get something like:

[image]